# HP printers does not print files

Tags: printing, hp, pdf

I use printer HP 1010, earlier it was HP PSC 1310, but the problem is still the same. When I need to print something, I click the button "print" (nevermind if it is a .doc file or .pdf, or open office format), printer takes sheet of paper, "print" and... it give back the same white piece of paper without any single printed letter. I do not know where the problem is, because I'm sure it is not a matter of device - I use HP supplies and it print either "test page" and "clean cartridges" correctly. I can add, that I bought my new printer a few months ago, because I had thought that it is problem with it. And then new printer printed ok, then less ok, but acceptable, and now there is the same trouble as earlier. Has someone any ideas what's the matter?

Comment: Are you using hplip drivers? Maybe updating them will help? Also note that there is a hp doctor built-in in HPlip. Try it.

Comment: I had a very odd problem with an HP printer. It refused to work with a 1500 byte MTU. So, does yours print from a windows or mac? If so, try forcing your MTU to 1498 bytes.

Comment: I use hplip, I try to change settings etc., no result.

Comment: Is your printer working on windows?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Ubuntu you, just use the command `sudo hp-setup` in the Terminal. But if you're using something like Xubuntu you have to install Hplip from the **Software Manager** first.

Comment: Well, I've got Ubuntu (14.04), i used this command, but there's still no improvement. I have no idea why it is like this, especially few months ago everything was ok.